# Sending time-consuming scripts via APIs

Tags: php, mysql, api

Various users will submit their phone number to get notified for certain service that I provide. As soon as I start providing the service, a SMS notification should be sent out to all those users who had signed up(submitted their phone number).

```
foreach($phone_numbers as $number)
   // api call to send the sms
   $msg->send($number);
endforeach
```

Now the thing that is confusing me is, at some point I can have like 1000 users signed up, and when the scripts runs automatically when I add that service, it will consume a lot of time to loop through 1000 number and make 1000 API calls.

Is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: why not adding a cronjob and send 100 SMS in per execution by setting the cron to run after every 10 minutes.

Comment: Does the API service you're using allow batch-sending? Many APIs allow batch runs where you can submit X jobs in one API request - rather than one job per API request.

Comment: You might check out the Gearman library.

Comment: You have two good approaches noted above.  Any good SMS service should allow bulk send.  Or if not, you can look at queuing up the messages in some manner.

Comment: @nickhar I am not sure. I will have to check with them. But most probably they dont. But thanks, I am sending them an email right now

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a message queue like RabbitMQ. That way, you could just push the task to the queue and have it handled by a separate process, which could run on a different server. It also has the advantage that it should be a bit more robust, since if it fails, your worker script can try again.

I haven't had occasion to use it with a PHP application, but I have used it with Celery for a Django app with good results. I found decent-looking PHP examples at http://blog.teqneers.com/2013/10/simple-spawn-rabbitmq-consumers-with-php/ and http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html.